# How do Promise.resolve() function works? I am getting two different output on passing rejected promise as argument to Promise.resolve() function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am passing rejected promise in the argument of Promise.resolve() function. In first case 1 am passing the rejected promise through a function foo(), and in the second case 2 am passing the rejected promise by creating a new promise in the argument of Promise.resolve() function.

Case 1:

```
function foo(){
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  reject("Function foo failed");
 });
}
Promise.resolve(foo)
.then(
()=>{console.log("Success");},
()=>{console.log("Failure");}
);
```

Case 2:

```
Promise.resolve(
new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{reject("Failure");
})
)
.then(
()=>{console.log("Success");},
()=>{console.log("Failure");}
);
```

In case 2, the output is as expected and the output is "Failure" . But in case 1 the output is "Success", but I am expecting "Failure" in this case (case 1) also because I am passing a rejected promise. So I want to ask why the output in case 1 is "Success" and not "Failure"?

Comment: In case 1 you maybe need call foo function

Comment: `Promise.resolve(foo)` is different from `Promise.resolve(foo())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure anyone has fully explained what is really going on here so I'll attempt a little more in-depth discussion of what's happen.

Let's look at what `Promise.resolve()` actually does.  It creates a new promise and takes the value you pass it and makes that the resolved value of the new promise.   The one exception is if the value you pass it is a promise itself, then it chains that promise to the newly created promise and the value of the newly created promise will track the value of the promise you passed it including whether it resolves or rejects.

So, now in your case 1:

```js
    function foo(){
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      reject("Function foo failed");
     });
    }
    
    Promise.resolve(foo).then(
        ()=>{console.log("Success");},
        ()=>{console.log("Failure");}
    );
```

The value you are passing `Promise.resolve()` is a function reference `foo`.  That function is not called.  So, what you get is a newly created promise who's resolved value is the function reference `foo` (essentially a pointer to function foo).  Notice that `foo()` is never called.  You're just passing around a reference to the function `foo`.

Now, in your case 2:

```js
    Promise.resolve(
        new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{reject("Failure");})
    ).then(
        ()=>{console.log("Success");},
        ()=>{console.log("Failure");}
    );
```

Here the value you are passing `Promise.resolve()` is a promise that gets rejected.  So, `Promise.resolve()` creates a new promise that will track the value and resolve/reject state of that promise.  So, you get the expects `"Failure"` output.

---

If we make case 3 where you actually called `foo()` and pass its return value to `Promise.resolve()` as in this:

```js
    function foo(){
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      reject("Function foo failed");
     });
    }
    
    // call foo() and pass its return value to Promise.resolve()
    Promise.resolve(foo()).then(
        ()=>{console.log("Success");},
        ()=>{console.log("Failure");}
    );
```

Then, you would get the expected "Failure" output.

Comment: Thank you.very well explained.

Comment: @kushagra - If this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper stackoverflow procedure.

Answer (score 1):

In first case, you are passing a reference to the function. When you pass something into `Promise.resolve()` which is not a promise- it automatically returns a resolved promise.

To get expected output on 1st case, put it like this:

`Promise.resolve(foo())` - notice the `foo()` which invokes the function foo instead of `foo` which just passes a reference.

Comment: Very precise explanation.